# Datatype for getting input for over 30 digits

Tags: java

I have a serious problem. I need to get a number say

```
123454466666666666666665454545454454544598989899545455454222222222222222
```

and give the total of that number. I was trying for a long time. I couldn't get the answer. The problem is I didn't know which data type to use. I have tried it long. It accepts only 18 digits. I have gone through `BigInteger`. But I couldn't make arithmetic operations with it. so help me out with this problem..

Comment: Whats a "total of that number". Just sum of all digits? Then you should use string.

Comment: Try string. Parse each character for integer and add all.

Comment: @DarshanLila That is pretty much, what BigInteger does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result from the below code.

```
String string = "123454466666666666666665454545454454544598989899545455454222222222222222";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    count += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(string.charAt(i)));
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1.Get it as a string
2.get length of it.
3.Loop through each character of it. 
4.check if the character is a number.
5.If yes parse it to int.
6.Add all numbers together in the loop

OR

Use BigDecimal
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use it as a `String`. That's the easiest way to go for the task at hand.

```
public class Test022 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "123454466666666666666665454545454454544598989899545455454222222222222222";
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            sum += s.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i can suggest using this code and the numbers as String

```
/**
 * Adds two non-negative integers represented as string of digits.
 *
 * @exception NumberFormatException if either argument contains anything other
 *            than base-10 digits.
 */
public static String add(String addend1, String addend2) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i1 = addend1.length() - 1, i2 = addend2.length() - 1, carry = 0;
          (i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0) || carry != 0;
          i1--, i2-- ) {
        int digit1 = i1 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend1.charAt(i1)));
        int digit2 = i2 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend2.charAt(i2)));

        int digit = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
        if (digit > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        buf.append(digit);
    }
    return buf.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger does support methods like add/multiply etc. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for details.

```
    BigInteger operand1 = new BigInteger("123454466666666666666665454545454454544598989899545455454222222222222222");
    BigInteger operand2 = new BigInteger("123454466666666666666665454545454454544598989899545455454222222222222222");
    System.out.println(operand1.add(operand2));
    System.out.println(operand1.subtract(operand2));
    System.out.println(operand1.multiply(operand2));
    System.out.println(operand1.divide(operand2));
```